# Function doesn't act on the slice of a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, function, mutable

I am trying to rotate an array `arr` of length `n` by `d` elements. I reversed the array, and then reversed two parts of my array `0 to n-d` and `n-d to n` to reach the result.

```py
from sys import stdin

def reverseArray(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)//2):
        arr[i], arr[len(arr)-i-1] = arr[len(arr)-i-1], arr[i]
    return

def rotate(arr, n, d):
    reverseArray(arr)
    reverseArray(arr[0:n-d])
    reverseArray(arr[n-d:n])
    return

# Taking Input Using fast I/O
def takeInput() :
    n = int(stdin.readline().rstrip())
    if n == 0:
        return list(), 0

    arr = list(map(int, stdin.readline().rstrip().split(" ")))
    return arr, n


#to print the array/list 
def printList(arr, n) : 
    for i in range(n) :
        print(arr[i], end = " ")
    print()


#main
t = int(stdin.readline().rstrip())

while t > 0 :
    
    arr, n = takeInput()
    d = int(stdin.readline().rstrip())
    rotate(arr, n, d)
    printList(arr, n)
    
    t -= 1
```

Input:

```
1 # Test cases
6 # n
1 3 6 11 12 17 # elements of arr
4 # d
```

Output:

My Output

```
17 12 11 6 3 1
```

Expected Output

```
12 17 1 3 6 11
```

I don't understand why my reverse function works on the whole array, but not on the slices of the array.
Since lists are mutable, I believe that my function should change the slices.

It works when I assign the slice to a variable, and then assign the reversed value to the slice again.

```py
def rotate(arr, n, d):
    reverseArray(arr)
    
    fp = arr[0:n-d]
    sp = arr[n-d:n]
    
    reverseArray(fp)
    arr[0:n-d] =  fp
    
    reverseArray(sp)
    arr[n-d:n] = sp
    
    return
```

Comment: A slice makes a copy, so you're not modifying the original list.

Comment: BTW, these are lists, not arrays.

Comment: Also, slow sample input and expected output

Comment: Oh, totally forgot about that.